# Moodle: get user picture from webservice

Tags: php, web-services, moodle

By using Moodle Web Service (REST) call `core_user_get_users_by_field` I successfully get my user details. One of the returned fields is `profileimageurl` that links to my user profile picture and look like this:

```
http://my_moodle_server/pluginfile.php/89/user/icon/f1
```

Unfortunately that link works only in a browser where I have already logged in, otherwise it will redirect to a standard user icon (the grey anonymous face).

So in order to get the actual picture form a client app that is using moodle web services I think I have to call `core_files_get_files` and pass correct values. So I tried to remap that link to calls paramenters like this:

```
contextid: 89
component: "user"
filearea: "icon"
itemid: 0
filepath: "/"
filename: "f1.png" (also tryed without .png)
and of course my valid token
```

but all I get is:

```
{"parents":[],"files":[]}
```

Parameters seem to be formally correct (otherwise I would get an exception) however I only get empty response which tells me that some values are not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the solution to my problem. I'm posting the answer here also because there's not much information about Moodle web service around...

First of all, `core_files_get_files` is not the way... it will only show files information, it won't give you the actual file contents (binary).

Fortunately, there's an equivalent URL to be used when calling from external client app:

http://my_moodle_server/**webservice**/pluginfile.php

It accepts the same parameters/format as http://my_moodle_server/pluginfile.php and in addition you can also pass your token for web service authentication.

So `profileimageurl` field returned by `core_user_get_users_by_field` which looks like this:

```
http://my_moodle_server/pluginfile.php/89/user/icon/f1
```

can be turned into

```
http://my_moodle_server/webservice/pluginfile.php/89/user/icon/f1?token=my_web_service_token
```

Also note that appending `?token=` parameter is required

Comment: i am facing same issue to get Myrpivate file list, how to get them from webservice part Here is URL that i had made         webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=3afe18c8697dac9518d59bb8f10429b4&wsfunction=core_files_get_files&moodlewsrestformat=json&contextid=2&component=&filearea=&itemid=0&filepath=

Comment: In the admin/webservice/service.php?id=2 page, we enable to downloading. This solve our problem